# Can not see the result of query in template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I want to see my query results in an html after a ajax get request.
Please find my code below,
def tanim_ajax(request):

```
#views.py
def tanim_ajax(request):

    if request.GET.get('q'):

        q = request.GET.get('q')
        results = Title.objects.filter(title__contains=q),
        print results
        return render_to_response('tanim/ajax.html',
                                    {'results':results},
                                    context_instance=RequestContext(request))

#models.py
class Title(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name="Başlık")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,verbose_name="Kategori")
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Everything works fine for template

```
{% for i in results %}
<br>{{i}}
{% endfor %}
```

I can see the result as `[<Title: foo>]` when i checked the`http://127.0.0.1:8000/tanimlar/tanim_ajax/?q=foo`url.

But when I have the following template

```
 {% for i in results %}
<br>{{i.title}}
{% endfor %}
```

I dont see any results. Any idea ?

Comment: code looks fine :) getting any errors ???

Comment: no errors at all. Just cant see any results, when I seek for the items of object.Template comes empty

Comment: just hard code some message in for loop like `<h1>title : </h1><br>` in your template may give some idea

Comment: still no item ony "Title:" appears

Comment: for how many times and are u seen any results by `print results` in your view ?

Comment: I see just one result.But there is only one foo though

Comment: solved :) by removing just `print result` hahaha :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're passing a QuerySet into the context. Instead, try appending values() to your query which will return a dictionary.

```
results = Title.objects.filter(title__contains=q).values()
```

Comment: Are you certain that the instance returned by your query has a title attribute set?

Comment: actually  'if request.GET.get('q'):
   q = request.GET.get('q')
   results = Title.objects.filter(title__contains=q).values()
   return render_to_response('tanim/ajax.html',
          {'results':results},' helped